# Restricting one site under Wordpress as Private in AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-alb, restrictions

I have configured multiple sites on WordPress and it is connected with **internet-faced ALB under AWS**.

Is it possible to restrict one site as private on ALB?

Remaining sites needs an public access.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe/Kinda. You could configure a routing rule in the ALB setup that matches on the site's hostname (ex. www.example.com) and configure the rule to NOT send it to your backend server/service. Instead you could return a static response or send it elsewhere. This would prevent the ALB from forwarding that traffic to your WordPress site. If all of the sites use the same hostname with different, but consistent, paths you could also match on the start of the path to accomplish the same thing. For private access you would need a 2nd internal ALB. Assuming by private you mean internal to the VPC.

Comment: What do you mean "private access"? Do you want to restrict so visitors have to be in a given country, have a specific IP, login, or something else?